# How to Properly SignOut Firebase auth after call DocumentSnapshot Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

So I try to create Sign-out button in a fragment `Home` but, everytime user SignOut, the app will crash and it caused by document snapshot.

this is my document snapshot code.

```
private fun loadProfile() {
    val user = mAuth!!.currentUser
    if (user != null) {
       ...//loading profile code
        }

        val uid = user.uid
        documentReference = db!!.collection("users").document(uid)
        documentReference!!.addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, e ->
            //this if returning null after user signout
            if (documentSnapshot!!.exists()) {
                if (documentSnapshot.get(KEY_HP) != null) {
                   ...//loading profile code


            }else {
                val intent = Intent(this@Home.activity, LoginActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
    } else {
        val intent = Intent(this@Home.activity, LoginActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

as you can see I desperately add `else` everywhere but that does not help.

this is my Sign-out method

```
private fun signOut() {
        mAuth!!.signOut()
        val intent = Intent(this@Home.activity, LoginActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)


    }
```

So, I need to properly signout without the app being crash

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: I already lookedup the LogCat, that's how I find out that `if (documentSnapshot!!.exists())` returning null and cause the app crash after sign-out,

Comment: What's the actual crash? Add that message to your question.

Comment: Also written that up already, the crash is caused by documentSnapshot returning null

Answer (score 1):

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

Use this to signout from Firebase. And then, if you try to perform any action of a logged in user, you won't be able to, you will have to login again.

Answer (score 0):

FUTURE REFERENCE

After fighting with the "sign-out" method for a couple days, I realized that if you have snapshot listeners attached within the activity, make sure you handle and return the error, as stated [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener), or else you may run into some Permission Errors and crashes.